# Есть ли функция отвечающая за повторное открытие приложения android?

Tags: android, activity

У меня в приложении есть стартовый экран с логином пользователя. Там есть поле логина, пароля и чекбокс для запоминания пользователя. Этот чекбокс пишет в память бул переменную которая проверяется в функции onCreate(). Так получается что при выборе чекбокса полезли глюки. Какого плана глюки:

1. Выбрали чекбокс ничего не ввели в поля, свернули приложение и открыли вновь - првоерка увидела что бул переменная тру и нас кинуло на следующий экран (вроде решено)
2. Выбрали чек ничего не ввели в поля, свернули приложение, открыли панель недавних приложений закрыли его, дальше опять открываем и нас кидает на след. экран. (не смог решить).
3. Есть функционал который пересоздает экран, при тех же условиях что и в 1 или 2 пунктах и дальше нас кидает на след экран. (решено)
4. Делаем все что в 1 или 2 пунктах, нажимаем на аппаратную или программную кнопку назад, и дальше после сворачивания опять открываем приложение, бросает на следующий экран. (решено)

Суть в чем, я хочу сделать так чтобы при чеканьи чекбокса и если у нас ничего не введено и дальше если вдруг у нас по каким-то причинам пересоздается активити и мне нужно чтобы эта бул переменная писалась как false. Вот что у меня получилось:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        sp = getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0);
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("hasVisited", false).apply();
            user.setChecked(false);
            startActivity(startMain);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        sp = getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0);
        final boolean hasVisited = sp.getBoolean("app_data", false);
        if (hasVisited) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("hasVisited", false).apply();
            user.setChecked(false);
        }

        super.onDestroy();
    }

@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        sp = getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0);
        final boolean hasVisited = sp.getBoolean("app_data", false);
        Log.w("MY_TAG", String.valueOf(hasVisited));
        if (hasVisited) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("hasVisited", false).apply();
            user.setChecked(false);
        }
        super.onPause();
    }
```

думал что есть функция onResume() которая решить часть моих нерешенных проблем, но я ее не нашел, есть только onPostResume(). Не знаю как решить то что я не смог сделать. Надеюсь на вашу помощь и ценные советы.

Comment: Ну кто же так делает :) Этот флаг надо писать не тогда, когда чекбокс кликается, а когда success scenario закончился, т.е. юзер залогинился успешно, тогда его и надо запоминать. Пока этого не произошло, запоминать нечего.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, можете более подробно объяснить что вы имеете в виду, потому что я часть понял из того что вы сказали, а часть нет)

Comment: Попробую перефразировать - не надо писать в преференсы вообще ничего, до тех пор, пока Вы не получили ответ от сервера об успешном логине. Только после этого Вы можете быть уверены, что всё введено верно и можно сохраняться.

Comment: все я понял спасибо) протупил немного